# Using the Webots Connector Device with ROS

Tags: ros, webots

I'm currently trying to make the Connector Device work with ROS. My first step was to just take one of the robots of the "connector.wbt" world and place it in a new world and switching the robots controller argument to "ros"as one can see below.

[image: s]

When I run the simulations all ROS services are advertised as expected. In the next step I enable the Connector using its corresponding service, where an integer needs to be specified (presence check Time Step) //presence_sensor/enable service as shown below:[image]

Now the topic is enabled, however no messages are published, while I'm expecting to see messages of type "webots_ros/Int8Stamped", which should give me zeros for the absence of a suitable connector.

[image]
Is there any idea if the problems lies on my side? Is the Connector-Ros-Interface working properly for you if you recreate the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely right, there was indeed a problem with the ros-connector interface.
This has been fixed just now here:

- https://github.com/omichel/webots/pull/672

This fix will be included in the nightly build of today (R2019b revision 1, available from tomorrow morning) that you can find here:

- https://github.com/omichel/webots/releases

Let us know if there are still problems.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the bug, I just tried it out with both (symmetric and active/passive connectors) and it seems to be working out as expected